# make 2 textviews stay one after another - Android

Tags: android

I want 2 textviews to stay something like this

`textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1 textview1|textView2 textView2 textView2 textView2`

The length of textview1 could be more than 1 line and textview2 must stay right after textview1 on the same line that textview1 ended. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a new TextViewUtil to handle such case and post it here in case anyone else is looking for this kind of trouble:

```
public class TextViewUtil {

public static void setClickableText(Context context, TextView view, String clickableText, OnClickListener listener) {

    CharSequence text = view.getText();
    String string = text.toString();
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    ClickSpan span = new ClickSpan(listener, resources.getColor(R.color.background_blue),
            resources.getColor(R.color.universal_profile_blue_link));

    int start = string.indexOf(clickableText);
    int end = start + clickableText.length();
    if (start == -1)
        return;

    if (text instanceof Spannable) {
        ((Spannable) text).setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        view.setText(text);
    } else {
        SpannableString s = SpannableString.valueOf(text);
        s.setSpan(span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        view.setText(s);
    }

    MovementMethod m = view.getMovementMethod();
    if (m == null || !(m instanceof LinkTouchMovementMethod)) {
        view.setMovementMethod(LinkTouchMovementMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use class

```
public class PredicateLayout extends ViewGroup {

public static final int DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_SPACING = 0;
public static final int DEFAULT_VERTICAL_SPACING = 0;
private final int horizontalSpacing;
private final int verticalSpacing;
private List<RowMeasurement> currentRows = Collections.emptyList();

public PredicateLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    TypedArray styledAttributes = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.RowLayout);
    horizontalSpacing = styledAttributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RowLayout_android_horizontalSpacing,
            DEFAULT_HORIZONTAL_SPACING);
    verticalSpacing = styledAttributes.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.RowLayout_android_verticalSpacing,
            DEFAULT_VERTICAL_SPACING);
    styledAttributes.recycle();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    final int widthMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(widthMeasureSpec);
    final int heightMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(heightMeasureSpec);
    final int maxInternalWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) - getHorizontalPadding();
    final int maxInternalHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec) - getVerticalPadding();
    List<RowMeasurement> rows = new ArrayList<RowMeasurement>();
    RowMeasurement currentRow = new RowMeasurement(maxInternalWidth, widthMode);
    rows.add(currentRow);
    for (View child : getLayoutChildren()) {
        LayoutParams childLayoutParams = child.getLayoutParams();
        int childWidthSpec = createChildMeasureSpec(childLayoutParams.width, maxInternalWidth, widthMode);
        int childHeightSpec = createChildMeasureSpec(childLayoutParams.height, maxInternalHeight, heightMode);
        child.measure(childWidthSpec, childHeightSpec);
        int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (currentRow.wouldExceedMax(childWidth)) {
            currentRow = new RowMeasurement(maxInternalWidth, widthMode);
            rows.add(currentRow);
        }
        currentRow.addChildDimensions(childWidth, childHeight);
    }

    int longestRowWidth = 0;
    int totalRowHeight = 0;
    for (int index = 0; index < rows.size(); index++) {
        RowMeasurement row = rows.get(index);
        totalRowHeight += row.getHeight();
        if (index < rows.size() - 1) {
            totalRowHeight += verticalSpacing;
        }
        longestRowWidth = Math.max(longestRowWidth, row.getWidth());
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(widthMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ? MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec) : longestRowWidth
            + getHorizontalPadding(), heightMode == MeasureSpec.EXACTLY ? MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec)
            : totalRowHeight + getVerticalPadding());
    currentRows = Collections.unmodifiableList(rows);
}

private int createChildMeasureSpec(int childLayoutParam, int max, int parentMode) {
    int spec;
    if (childLayoutParam == LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) {
        spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(max, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    } else if (childLayoutParam == LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT) {
        spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(max, parentMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ? MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED
                : MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    } else {
        spec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(childLayoutParam, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    }
    return spec;
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int leftPosition, int topPosition, int rightPosition, int bottomPosition) {
    final int widthOffset = getMeasuredWidth() - getPaddingRight();
    int x = getPaddingLeft();
    int y = getPaddingTop();

    Iterator<RowMeasurement> rowIterator = currentRows.iterator();
    RowMeasurement currentRow = rowIterator.next();
    for (View child : getLayoutChildren()) {
        final int childWidth = child.getMeasuredWidth();
        final int childHeight = child.getMeasuredHeight();
        if (x + childWidth > widthOffset) {
            x = getPaddingLeft();
            y += currentRow.height + verticalSpacing;
            if (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                currentRow = rowIterator.next();
            }
        }
        child.layout(x, y, x + childWidth, y + childHeight);
        x += childWidth + horizontalSpacing;
    }
}

private List<View> getLayoutChildren() {
    List<View> children = new ArrayList<View>();
    for (int index = 0; index < getChildCount(); index++) {
        View child = getChildAt(index);
        if (child.getVisibility() != View.GONE) {
            children.add(child);
        }
    }
    return children;
}

protected int getVerticalPadding() {
    return getPaddingTop() + getPaddingBottom();
}

protected int getHorizontalPadding() {
    return getPaddingLeft() + getPaddingRight();
}

private final class RowMeasurement {
    private final int maxWidth;
    private final int widthMode;
    private int width;
    private int height;

    public RowMeasurement(int maxWidth, int widthMode) {
        this.maxWidth = maxWidth;
        this.widthMode = widthMode;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    public boolean wouldExceedMax(int childWidth) {
        return widthMode == MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED ? false : getNewWidth(childWidth) > maxWidth;
    }

    public void addChildDimensions(int childWidth, int childHeight) {
        width = getNewWidth(childWidth);
        height = Math.max(height, childHeight);
    }

    private int getNewWidth(int childWidth) {
        return width == 0 ? childWidth : width + horizontalSpacing + childWidth;
    }
}
```

}

xml:

```
<com.yourpackage.PredicateLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

       <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView1" />
       <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView1" />
       <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="TextView2" />

    </com.yourpackage.PredicateLayout>
```

**EDIT:**
you need create xml under /res/values/attrs.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RowLayout">
    <attr name="android:verticalSpacing" />
    <attr name="android:horizontalSpacing" />
</declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: can you provide the styleable attributes as well? I'm trying to test this out

Comment: which you can create xml under /res/values/attrs.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="RowLayout">
        <attr name="android:verticalSpacing" />
        <attr name="android:horizontalSpacing" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>

Comment: this does not work the way I explained above. When the text is on 1 line, it works, but when the text is longer than 1 line, the next tetview jumps to a new line

Answer (score 0):

three way that I know,maybe better way exist:

1)load your text in Html and set it for text view (you can use html style and...)

```
String text = "<font color=#cc0029>"+text1+"</font> <font color=#ffcc00>"+text2+"</font>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

2)load your text in one text view but set spannable for each part of text.
3) create custom TextView class and compute length of text then if bigger than you want set another textview layout below this one